# Can we save the output in cmd into txt file or environment variables

Tags: azure, azure-devops, environment-variables, azure-cli, bearer-token

I want save the output from cmd prompt to text file or environment variables.

For Ex In cmd prompt I executed

```
az account get-access-token
```

The output will be

```
{"access-token" : token,
 "expiresOn" :
 "Subscription" :
 "Teant" :
 "tokenType" : }
```

How to save the this dict into any file or can we save access-token into environment variable or how to extract the access-token in cmd prompt

I am trying to implement this method in devops pipeline. Any idea how can I reuse the Only access-token in same script in azure cli or set an pipeline variable and reuse it

this my script

```
curl --netrc --request POST \
https://<databricks-instance>/api/2.0/secrets/scopes/create \
--header "Content-Type: application/json" \
--header "Authorization: Bearer <token>" \
--header "X-Databricks-Azure-SP-Management-Token: <management-token>" \
--data @create-scope.json
```

So In bash script the first command will be `az account get-access-token`

from this I will get the dict, so in the command will be request Post in this how to pass access-token where the management-token is there in the same script

Comment: Have you tried something like `az account get-access-token > test.txt`? It should create `test.txt` file with data.

Comment: Thanks! got it 

Any idea how to set only access-token into pipeline variable or store into variable group in cd/ci pipelines in azure devops

Comment: I have no idea. Sorry.

Comment: Ok thanks, I have updated the question 
If you know let me know

Answer (score 0):

Try using the logging command to set the pipeline variable. See [Set variables in scripts](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/set-variables-scripts?view=azure-devops&tabs=bash) for details.

You can run `az account get-access-token --query accessToken --output json` to get the `accessToken` and set the value to a variable. After that, you can use the variable in the subsequent tasks in pipeline.

The following yaml file for your reference:

```
steps:
- task: AzureCLI@2
  displayName: 'Azure CLI '
  inputs:
    azureSubscription: 'service-connection'
    scriptType: ps
    scriptLocation: inlineScript
    inlineScript: |
     $accessToken = az account get-access-token --query accessToken --output json
     Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=Token]$accessToken "

- powershell: |
   # Write your PowerShell commands here.
   Write-Host "SecretToken" $(Token)
  displayName: 'Test the variable'
```

Comment: @Syamala Kumar Rama Koti Reddy Any update? Have you resoled the issue by the solution?